# How should I allocate staging versions of shared services across VPCs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, cloud, production-environment, amazon-vpc

It's a common design pattern to have separate VPCs per environment in AWS:

- prod
- staging
- dev
- shared (like CI, metrics, logging)

If I write a new application service, I would have 1 copy of it in each of {prod, staging, dev} VPCs.

However, what do I do for prod/staging versions of common services (like metrics)? If it's straight out of the box, I could just put a single copy in the `shared` VPC. But if it's some custom in-house version, and I want to do development on it, should I put both the prod AND staging version of that common service in the same `shared` VPC?

Answer (score 0):

Each environment should be in separate VPC to bring security and easy maintenance

- dev
- staging
- production

These environments will have an application hosted and it can be connected by VPC peering in case of allowing the traffic.

> Then there would be some log and application monitoring tool dashboard running to monitor all the environments
>   Also, there is deployment like Jenkins running to deploy the application code on all environments.

Ideally, log monitoring and application monitoring tools can be in `shared VPC`, most of the time logs and metrics sent via an agent installed from the host machine over `https or UDP/TCP` protocol so networking won't be an issue.

In the case of CI tool, it can be hosted in shared VPC with deployment to handle all environments by splitting the views for deployment jobs and control the access by using role management plugin for multiple dev teams. However, it's always better to have dev/standby and production deployment/Jenkins to test the development and testing of new things in terms of plugin upgrade and dependencies before rather than applying it directly on production.

Comment: For the logs + metrics monitoring, I understand that it would be in the `shared VPC`, but what about the `staging` version of those `logs` and `metrics monitoring` services? Would those also be in the `shared VPC`? Do you have an example of this architecture in use?

Comment: For staging version of `logs` and `metrics` also you can push those logs to the same setup in the shared VPC. for example in Splunk you can split the logs based on the environment by different indexes. https://answers.splunk.com/answers/507415/what-is-the-best-practice-to-manage-the-same-index.html If you want to restrict team to access nonprod and production logs/metrics, then it could be better to have a different setup for each.

Answer (score 0):

First to answer your question directly.  You need a platform environment.  This environment will be for all the development and configuration that you build your application on.   It will include your in house metrics system plus all the infrastructure include AWS services such as VPCs, cloudwatch, logging, etc.

Your workflow environment would look like this.

platform -> dev -> staging -> prod

Depending on your platform process it could be 1 environment (platform dev) or you might have 2 (platform dev and platform staging).  And platform prod is your application dev environment.

The bigger picture

You need to move your environments up a level and do them at the account level.  So you would have 4 different AWS accounts.

- platform dev
- platform staging (optional)
- application dev
- application staging
- application prod
- management for shared (like CI, metrics, logging)
- AWS management account (AWS Control Tower and Organizations)

This has a few benefits:

- You can setup each environment exactly the same with either cloudformation or terraform. You are automating each environment write? Just say yes.
- You get better access control and don't have to worry about your prod environment when working in dev.
- You would have VPC access from the management VPC to each VPC in your prod/staging/dev environments then you can do VPC to VPC peering.

AWS provides 2 services to help manage multiple accounts.
[AWS Control Tower](https://aws.amazon.com/controltower/)
[AWS Organizations](https://aws.amazon.com/organizations/)
Start with Control Tower as it will setup your Organization for you.

And if you want scale this to multiple applications you only have to duplicate your application dev/staging/prod environment.